# I know how to write and if statement as a formula, but not in a script

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know next to nothing about writing scripts in Google Sheets, but I'm hoping to learn!

I've gotten a cell to increase by 1 when I click a drawing, but I need for the cell to go back to 1 after it gets to 12.  So it continually counts from 1 up to 12.

I have this as the original script.  I know how to write and if statement as a formula, but not in a script.  Can anyone help?

```
function incrementup() {
  if (U38<13) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('U38').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('U38').getValue() + 1);
  } else { 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('U38').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('U38').1);

}
}
```

Comment: Also bear in mind that a follow up question should be posted as a new question rather than an edit of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The scripts (Google Apps Scripts) for Google Sheets are written in JavaScript.

The syntax for an if statement is

```
if condition statement
```

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: thanks @Rubén.  Can you help me reference the cell U38?  I'm trying to check if that is less than 13, but I don't know how to reference it.

Answer (score 1):

Ooooh.  I figured it out (probably a lot messier than it needs to be)...

```
function incrementup() {
  if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('U38').getValue()<12) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('U38').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('U38').getValue() + 1);
  } else { 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('U38').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('U38').getValue() *0 + 1); 
  }
}
```